# How to insert multiple data from listbox to database

Tags: php

Please look this link to see the code use by me

```
 <pre>
      http://jsfiddle.net/JaavS/
  </pre>

 <pre>

    step1: select values in List A
    step2: Move the values to list b
    Step3:click save to database button

 </pre>
```

After step3, the item in the list b values to be store in database. Can any one help me

Comment: I suggest you read the php documentation and study a few examples. This is simple usage of php and its extensions. It is all documented. And has been answered here millions of times before.

Comment: What is your database engine? There is multiple way to complete this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your selects a name:

Select1:

```
    <select name ="list1[]" id="list1" multiple="multiple" rows=2>
    <option value=1>Option 1</option>
    <option value=2>Option 2</option>
    <option value=3>Option 3</option>
    <option value=4>Option 4</option>
    <option value=5>Option 5</option>
    <option value=6>Option 6</option>
    </select>
```

Select2:

```
    <select name="list2[]" id="list2" multiple="multiple" rows=2>

    </select>
```

In your php file:

```
 <?php
 //List 2 
 foreach ($_POST['list2'] as $selectedOption)
 {
   $query = "INSERT INTO table (option) VALUES ('$selectedOption')";
   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: http://www.phpbook.net/get-multiple-select-box-values-in-php.html check this for clear explanation